# Copy data from one sheet to another based on a specific key value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy data from one sheet to another in Google Docs using a script. Both sheets are part of the same Spreadsheet doc. I would like to copy the information from the first sheet to the second sheet if the value in column A is "Name".
I have basic knowledge of JavaScript and so far have managed to come up with the following.

```
function copytoo(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);// selects the first sheet in     your spreadsheet
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();// data is a 2D array, index 0 = col A
  var target = new Array();// this is a new array to collect data
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate in the array, row by row
    if (data[n][0]=="Name"){ ;// if condition is true copy the whole row to target
    taget.push(data[n]);// copy the whole row
    }//if
    }//for
  var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]); //second sheet of your spreadsheet
  sh2.getRange(1,1,target.length,target[0].length).setValues();// paste the selected     values in the 2cond sheet in one batch write
}//function
```

When I run the above - I get the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 13, file "Code")

Comment: Is the error not clear or what are you having problems with? Which one is line 13?

Answer (score 1):

Likely source of the problem:

```
taget.push(data[n]);// copy the whole row
^^^^^
```

You probably meant `target`. As it is, you'll run into a problem with:

```
target[0].length
```

Since you never pushed anything to `target`, there is no `target[0]` defined, so of course it has no `length` property.

Even if you fix `taget`, you have the risk of this error unless you either guarantee that there is a `target[0]` that has a `length` property, or skip the operation when `target.length === 0`.

Comment: Hi @Mogsdad, I know this is an old post. But I just want to ask what do you mean by "unless you either guarantee that there is a target[0] that has a length property, or skip the operation when target.length === 0.". I mean how do you do this?

Comment: @novice See [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). You could then use `if (target[0] && target[0].hasOwnProperty("length")) {..}`.